# Load jQuery with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have a problem loading jQuery with RequireJS. I need to load it only once in my application, instead of loading it in every file I write. I have the following project:

```
my_project
    |
    |____ js
    |     |
    |     |____ jquery-1.7.2.min.js
    |     |
    |     |____ my_file.js
    |     |
    |     |____ my_file2.js
    |     |
    |     |____ my_file3.js
    |     |
    |     |____ jquery_loader.js
    |     |
    |     |____ loader.js
    |     
    |____ index.html
```

I want to load jQuery only once and use it in any of the my_file*.js, without changing their code. So I have written a jquery_loader.js with this code:

```
require.config ({
  baseUrl: "/js",
  paths: { 
    jquery: "jquery-1.7.2.min"
  },
  shim: {
    "jquery": {
      exports: "$"     
    }
  }
});

requirejs (
  [ 
    "jquery"
  ],

  function($){
    console.log("jquery loaded");
  }
);
```

And then I tried to load it in another file like this:

```
require.config ({
  baseUrl: "/js",
  paths: {    
    file: "my-file",
    file2: "my-file2",
    file3: "my-file3"
  },
  shim: {
    "file": ["jquery_loader"],
    "file2": ["jquery_loader"],
    "file3": ["jquery_loader"],
  }
});

requirejs (
  [
    "file",
    "file2",
    "file3"
  ],

  function(file){
    console.log("file loaded");
  }
);
```

(my-file.js only contains some jQuery stuff, like $("body").addClass("..."); $("#id").append("..."))

But I am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I understand I am not loading jQuery in the correct way, so I would appreciate some help about it.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: A fiddle would be the best but at least include your architecture ie. where the js codes are executed (body / head which file etc.)

Comment: Thank you @AliNaciErdem. I have edited my post and included my project's architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this scheme:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js_folder/',    
    paths: { 
    'jquery' : 'path/to/jquery'
    }    
})
```

then you can use it

```
define([ "jquery" ], function($){

});
```

Comment: Thank you @Evgeniy, it did the trick. I finally put it in my jquery_loader file and it woked fine.

Comment: I didn't get it? @Genzotto How it's possible to write the jQuery code outside the function using this?

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked to me. I put the define clause in my jquery_loader and everything was nice.

Comment: @Genzotto updated my answer to match this and make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

You can put this line in your requirejs config file to load jquery.

```
require(["jquery"]);
```

Hope it will work. Thanks.

Comment: Thank your for your answer @KuldeepVithlani. I tried it in both files but nothing happened. Any more ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Before calling jQuery functions, you should wait for it to become available.

main HTML contents;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script data-main="js/" src="js/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id = "element" style = "background-color:red;position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
        <script>

            require.config ({
              baseUrl: "js/",
              paths: {    
                file: "loader"
              }
            });

            requirejs ( [   "file" ], function(file){
                console.log("file loaded");
                //Can use jQuery now
              }
            );

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

loader.js which is in js/ folder;

```
require.config ({
  baseUrl: "js/",
  paths: { 
    jquery: "jquery-1.7.2.min"
  }
});

define([ "jquery" ], function($){

});
```

---

Just as I suspected. There is indeed;

```
define([ "jquery" ], function($){

});
```

thanks to Evgeniy. I have updated my answer to match this and make the things clearer.

Comment: Thank you @AliNaciErdem. I tried this but I still get the same error message.

Comment: The above code works just fine using RequireJS 2.1.11. Which version are you using? BTW you should try to access jQuery inside function($){console.log("can use jQuery");} where it is available. If still getting the same error, then it's not related to requireJS I think.

Comment: Thank you @AliNaciErdem. I am using the version you say, but my problem is that I need to use jQuery outside function($), in any other files. If I use it inside this function, it works.

Comment: @Genzotto so you should also state this in your question... And I think that is not possible since the whole procedure is asynchronous...